# USB Wifi Adapter connected to Kali Vbox but absent in ifconfig

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux, wifi-configuration, ifconfig

I installed *VirtualBox-6.1.12-139181* for Windows 10 with *Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.12* and imported the latest Kali VirtualBox Image *kali-linux-2020.2a-vbox-amd64* from [offensive-security](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/#1572305786534-030ce714-cc3b)

I bought a *Realtek 802.11n* USB WiFi adapter to work with in Kali Virtual Machine and it works with my Windows 10 immediately as plugged in. I set up a NAT Network and I added the corresponding USB Filter to my Virtual Machine USB settings to enable Kali to detect and use it as an external WiFi adapter.

When I boot up Kali and choose the USB adapter from *Devices -> USB -> Realtek 802.11n*, the device gets ticked and my Windows 10 stops recognizing it. But no Wireless capabilities appear in my network interface.

Running `ifconfig` in terminal only displays `eth0` and `lo` but there is no `wlan0`

To confirm whether Kali recognizes the USB, I ran `lsusb` and it clearly displays

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n`

Running `dmesg` on plugging the adapter gives this:

```
[ 3993.055075] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=f179, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 3993.055082] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3993.055086] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n [ 3993.055091] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 3993.055095] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00E0203010B
```

I am new to Linux and Kali and Virtual Machines so I have no idea what is wrong or what to do. I have spent like 5 hours on this and some people have asked to run commands but they just don't work. I have also tried app-compat commands but even if that shows `wlan0` and `wlan1` in `ifconfig`, none of those represent my USB WiFi adapter since the WiFi still doesn't discover or connect to APs and more importantly, they appear static since unplugging my USB adapter makes no difference.

Kindly help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the wireless adapter driver in Kali?  https://virtuallyonit.com/2018/09/10/install-a-wireless-adapter-on-kali-linux/

Comment: *"I bought a Realtek 802.11n USB WiFi adapter..."* -- That is not descriptive enough.  Which Realtek chipset does it use?  Learn how to access the system log, i.e. the `dmesg` command, for salient messages when a USB device is connected to the host..

Comment: @John I did all the steps in the link but I still cannot see any Wireless adapter available

Comment: It is possible the adapter is not compatible with Kali.

Comment: @John @sawdust Running `dmesg` on plugging the adapter gives this:

`[ 3992.538700] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci`

`[ 3993.055075] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=f179, bcdDevice= 0.00`

`[ 3993.055082] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3`

`[ 3993.055086] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n`

`[ 3993.055091] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek`

`[ 3993.055095] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00E0203010BF`

Comment: Your first stumbling block to overcome is installing the proper device driver.  There is a Linux driver for that WiFi adapter, [rtl8188fu](https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu), but it does not seem to be even in the mainline kernel.  See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiBnf3A6t_qAhVGJTQIHZnQAEUQFjAHegQICBAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fli969-200.members.linode.com%2Fpuppy%2Fviewtopic.php%3Fp%3D1042499%26sid%3D79150b74e62662a44cf507afe2ddf8b3&usg=AOvVaw1TxhMdz6CuORvDS4jQwTEC

Comment: Or try https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiBnf3A6t_qAhVGJTQIHZnQAEUQIDAHegQICBAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcache.googleusercontent.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dcache%3AovTJj2cGq28J%3Ali969-200.members.linode.com%2Fpuppy%2Fviewtopic.php%253Fp%253D1042499%2526sid%253D79150b74e62662a44cf507afe2ddf8b3%2B%26cd%3D8%26hl%3Den%26ct%3Dclnk%26gl%3Dus%26client%3Dubuntu&usg=AOvVaw3yvy9vdCg5IMiP7uYdc4iA

Comment: Also relevant: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?48583-wireless-adapter-problem-rtl8188ftv&p=94925

Comment: @sawdust How do you know I require `rtl8188fu` driver. Also, the link you have provided is pretty complicated to follow for a linux noob like me but I guess I will try to do something about it

Comment: Ok googling for drivers for `rtl8188fu` and installing one through GitHub did work but the new problem is the error `Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) : SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.` Tried this with a different driver too. Same issue. I think my adapter doesn't support Monitor Mode?

Answer (score 0):

install drivers first may solve the issue:
https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.